# Count and number each occurrence of a duplicate row(based on the values of 2 variables) in R

Tags: r, loops

```
a                b            #Encounter

1           112233              1

2           334455              1

1           112233              2

3           445566              1

2           334455              2

2           334455              3

3           445566              2

3           445566              3

3           445566              4
```

How would I calculate #Encounter, given column a and b, on R?

*The Excel code would be: =countifs(a(Range), a, b(Range), b)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option in `base R` would be to use `ave`

```
df1$Encounter <- with(df1, ave(seq_along(a), a, b, FUN = seq_along))
df1$Encounter
#[1] 1 1 2 1 2 3 2 3 4
```

---

Or in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Encounter := rowid(a, b)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), b = c(112233L, 
 334455L, 112233L, 445566L, 334455L, 334455L, 445566L, 445566L, 
  445566L)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```